# Suggest a database for key with multiple values , highly scalable

Tags: nosql, cassandra, redis, key-value, riak

We have data with key-multipleValues. Each key can have around 500 values (each value will be around 200-300 chars) and the number of such keys will be around 10 million. Major operation is to check for a value given a key.

I've been using mysql for long time where i've got 2 options: one row for each keyvalue, one row for each key with all values in a text field.But these does not seem efficient to me as the first model has lot of rows,redundancies and second model text field will become very large .

I am considering using nosql database for this purpose, i've used mongodb before and i dont think it is suitable for my current case. keyvalue based or column family based nosql db would be better.It need not be distributed.Someone who used riak,redis,cassandra etc pls share your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: Use a proven, stable SQL product.

Comment: I'm just curious (for my own problem) - why is MongoDB unsuitable for your case?

Comment: Thanks, but i don't remember why i thought so anymore :). Ended up using Redis and i am quite happy with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it seems some sort of Key-value store will be better for you comparing relational DB.

The data itself seem to be a non-relational, why store in a relational storage? It seems valid to use something like Cassandra.

I think a typical data-structure for this data to store will be a column family, with Key as Row-key and Columns as value.

```
MyDATA: (ColumnFamily)
  RowKey=>Key
    Column1=>val1
    Column2=>val2
    ...
    ...
    ColumnN=valN
```

The data would look like (JSON notation):

```
MyDATA (CF){
    [
      {key1:[{val1-1:'', timestamp}, {val1-2:'', timestamp}, .., {val1-500:'', timestamp}]},
      {key2:[{val2-1:'', timestamp}, {val2-2:'', timestamp}, .., {val2-500:'', timestamp}]},
      ...
      ...
    ]
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try the direct, normalized approach: One table with this schema:

```
id (primary key)
key
value
```

You have one row for every key->value relation

Add an index for each column, and lookup should be reasonably efficient. Have you profiled any of this to exhibit a bottleneck?

Comment: i will have 10 million keys, each with 500 vals, so 5 billion rows. I dont think anyone should profile to know how mysql performs then :)

Comment: @kaka: It's better to have an index on the values directly than to perform 10 million string operations!

Comment: sorry, did not get you, pls explain.I should query with a key to get the corresponding values

Comment: You said that your main application was looking up values. Doing that will be much faster if you have an index on the values!

Comment: yeah, but i need to look up depending on the key too, worried about billion+ rows. Anyways thanks for the input, that definitely helped.

Answer (score 2):

This does map straightforwardly to Cassandra.  Row key will be your model key, and your model values will be column names (yes, names) in Cassandra.  You can leave the Cassandra column value empty, or add metadata there such as timestamp if that would be useful.

Comment: Any specific advantages over others? Will read more about it ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is beyond the scale of MySQL on a single machine.  You'll need to tune inserts or it'll take forever to load.  You might also consider compressing your values using COMPRESS() or in your app directly.  Might save you 50% or so.

Redis is basically an in-memory database, so it's probably out.  Riak might be a decent choice or HBase or Cassandra.

Comment: Are you speaking of solution where i store each value in a row? never heard of mysql on a single machine with >2 billion rows, its great if it performs good